# unable to save workbook in xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

Unable to save a workbook using xlwings. Below is the code, loc contains the excel file name

```
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings import Book
print(xw.__version__)
app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = Book(loc)
wb.sheets['crosst'].range('AJ2:CH9999').value=''

wb.save(loc)
app.quit()
```

below is the response, but when I check the Excel file, the contents are not cleared?

```
0.24.6

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the file under a new name, not under the same name.

```py
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings import Book
print(xw.__version__)
app = xw.App(visible=False)
wb = Book(loc)
wb.sheets['crosst'].range('AJ2:CH9999').value=''

wb.save(loc1)
app.quit()
```

where `loc1` is another name.

Ensure also that your cells are correct.